# Accessing Claims Principal in EF DB Context

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have to access the claims of the currently logged in user in my DbContext  in my EF6 implementation in C#. I am not able to access the request context / User principal inside the DB context. I am sure that this could be done but missing some vital piece to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal. This might help. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thanks That worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Amanvir in the comments, you can use the threads `CurrentPrincipal`.
I have (and I still do) used this in my dbcontexts:

```
private ClaimsPrincipal GetCurrentPrincipal()
{
    return Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
}
```